# Transaction type safety

Tags: haskell

I have a Transaction monad that looks like:

`newtype Transaction t m a = .. my monad stack here ..`

`t` is a phantom type I use to make sure the transactions I chain up apply to the same backend store.

My main loop's iteration uses a type like:

`Transaction DB IO (Widget (Transaction DB IO ()))`

The above type means: "A transaction that generates a UI Widget whose user inputs translate to transactions to execute".

Additionally, I have:

`data Property m a = Property { get :: m a, set :: a -> m () }`

which is extremely useful (especially due to its ability to compose with FCLabels.

I make an awful lot of use of `Property (Transaction t m)` to generate my transactions.

**Now, I want the type system to guarantee that the Transaction that generates the Widget is a read-only transaction, and the transactions the widget generates are allowed to be read-write transactions.**

Apparently, I could just add another phantom type to the transaction, but this has two problems:

- It would require explicit conversions from `Transaction ReadOnly` to `Transaction ReadWrite` or type-class hackery to allow monadic composition between read and write primitives. This I think I can solve.
- The Property data constructor, in order to contain the writer, always requires a read/write operation which would force the "m" to be a ReadWrite transaction. I would not be able to re-use a property in the context of both a read-write and a read-only transaction.

I am looking for a good way to get the above-mentioned type-safety without losing the above traits of the design.

Comment: As you point out, phantom types for tracking read-only/read-write could solve problem, provided you have a function like `liftRORW :: Transaction ReadOnly t m a -> Transaction ReadWrite t m a`.  This seems like a pretty solid approach.

I don't think I understand the `Property` issue you brought up.

Comment: A cast to change the phantom type is indeed important, but only needs to be used rarely. For the most part, you can make a function that can be either part of a ReadOnly or ReadWrite block free in the phantom type.

This is sort of a poor man's subtyping.

Comment: Also, you can change Property to be:
`data Property m a = Property { get :: forall free. m free a, set :: a -> m ReadWrite () }`

although I don't know about interop with that and FCLabels.

Comment: I don't see why you are using a concrete type "DB" for the argument to the "t" type parameter.  From your description I'd have thought this was like the ST monad, where you have similar non-mixing requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the type-checker to enforce a distinction between Read-Only and Read-Write transactions, then the two must necessarily be distinct types.  Working from there, this solution presents itself:

```
data Property rm wm a = Property { get :: rm a, set :: a -> wm () }
```

There are a lot of variations of this approach.  Instead of distinct monads, you could have a monad with different context parameters:

```
newtype Transaction t c m a = .. my monad stack here

data Property mc c1 c2 a = Property { get :: mc c1 a, set :: a -> mc c2 () }
```

Here `mc` is a monad constructor; it needs the context parameter to make a monad.  Even though this uses more parameters, I prefer it because it emphasizes the similarities of the monads.

For functions that require reading or writing, consider using type classes.

```
newtype ReadOnly = ReadOnly

newtype ReadWrite = ReadWrite

class ReadContext rm where

class WriteContext rm where

instance ReadContext ReadOnly where
instance ReadContext ReadWrite where

instance WriteContext ReadWrite where

someGetter :: ReadContext c => Transaction t c m a

someSetter :: WriteContext c => a -> Transaction t c m ()
```

This should limit the amount of casts/lifting you need to do, while still enforcing type safety.